# Wireless won't associate after 12.04 upgrade

Tags: 12.04, wireless, atheros, dell-vostro

I have a problem connecting to my wireless when I upgraded to 12.04 from 10.04. I have the Atheros 9285 card and it's using the ath9k driver.

The failure is:

```
[ 3262.329542] wlan0: authenticate with 00:26:88:e6:db:34 (try 1)
[ 3262.331556] wlan0: authenticated
[ 3262.361303] wlan0: associate with 00:26:88:e6:db:34 (try 1)
[ 3262.365295] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:26:88:e6:db:34 (capab=0x411 status=12 aid=0)
[ 3262.365301] wlan0: 00:26:88:e6:db:34 denied association (code=12)
[ 3262.385620] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:26:88:e6:db:34 by local choice (reason=3)
```

It occurs only when I connect to a router set to WPA TKIP. Works fine with WPA AES.
Is this a driver problem or something in nm? I've seen similar reports with other drivers.

When this occurs, nm seems to report that I am connected for 30 sec (though there is no connection) so this may relate to other bug reports.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a comment rather than an answer to your question. I didn't think I'd have enough room in a comment so I used the answer format.

You don't explain in your question why you want to be able to use *WPA TKIP*. Frankly, if *AES* will work it is probably a better choice than *TKIP*, especially if you are using 802.11n (and your  Atheros 9285 follows the 802.11n spec).

The 802.11n spec states that the high throughput rates (link rates above 54 Mbps) can **not** be enabled unless you either (1) use no security  or (2) use *WPA2 AES*.
Ref: [***5 Ways To Fix Slow 802.11n Speed***](http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/wireless/wireless-basics/30664-5-ways-to-fix-slow-80211n-speed)

I am not trying to tell you to ignore the problem you are asking about. I just wanted to suggest that if you can use *WPA2 AES* that is probably what you to do.

Comment: 1) Yes, by nm I meant Network Manager. This is the normal connect to the internet application that is started when you log on.

Comment: Regarding TKIP - this is controlled by the wireless access point. I can change this on my home system, but not for the university system, internet cafees etc. That's why it's important that all common access protocals be supported.

Comment: I tried switching to the WICP network interface from nm. I get the same problem of not associating with the access point. Will someone PLEASE fix the damn driver...